# Python 3 assigning list instance

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a small (I hope) problem with Python (3.8)

Let's say we have a list :

```
mylist=['item1','item2','item3']
```

Now, let's say I create a dict with a key:value pair:

```
mydict={'key1':mylist}
```

Then :

```
print(str(mydict))
```

Properly outputs :

```
{'key1':['item1','item2','item3']}
```

But, if I now append a value to mylist with :

```
mylist.append('item A')
```

I notice that :

```
print(str(mydict))
```

now outputs :

```
{'key1':['item1','item2','item3','item A']}
```

How can I avoid this? I want the list in mydict not to be updated...
In other words, I want the mydict entry to contain the instance of mylist (before the append)...

Comment: So you want the list in the dict to be a *distinct copy* of the original list?

Comment: Exactly. I don't want it to be "dynamically" updated...

Comment: Then you need to make a copy to assign to the dict.

Comment: So, this means that with = I point to the list...at any time, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a copy of the list with:

```
mydict={'key1':mylist.copy()}
```

This way the dictionary will contain a new, separate list of items.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution would be to reassign the initial mylist to another variable (say mylist0), then use this for the dictionary assignment, so it does not update.  This would work in a loop as well (if that is the intent) so long as you reassign mylist0 within the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure this works. That's what I thought too initially but this has the same result. When mylist changes, mylist0 changes as well and so does the dict... With list.copy() instead of = it seems to work...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).